# SQL promise in NodeJS returning empty brackets, but when same query is executed in SQL workbench, it returns the correct data

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs, object

I have some code in NodeJS meant for a React app. It's purpose is very simple. To execute a SELECT MySQL query, and return the correct data. However, I've run into multiple problems with it. First, I had to make it an asynchronous query, which I did. However, when I log the final answer in the console, I get an object of data.

```
Query {
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { error: [Function],
     packet: [Function],
     timeout: [Function],
     end: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: undefined,
  _callSite: Error
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:201:25)
    at Promise (C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\src\api\main.js:25:21)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at getResult (C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\src\api\main.js:24:21)
    at C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\src\api\main.js:38:16
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Anirudh\Desktop\Books Searcher\book-searcher\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM books_catalouge WHERE Author = "Alex Scarrow"',
  values: undefined,
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  _connection:
   Connection {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     config:
      ConnectionConfig {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '3306',
        localAddress: undefined,
        socketPath: undefined,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'pokemon2345',
        database: 'my_books',
        connectTimeout: 10000,
        insecureAuth: false,
        supportBigNumbers: false,
        bigNumberStrings: false,
        dateStrings: false,
        debug: undefined,
        trace: true,
        stringifyObjects: false,
        timezone: 'local',
        flags: '',
        queryFormat: undefined,
        pool: undefined,
        ssl: false,
        multipleStatements: false,
        typeCast: true,
        maxPacketSize: 0,
        charsetNumber: 33,
        clientFlags: 455631 },
     _socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: true,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 0,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        _idleTimeout: 10000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 16067,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 20,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 13 },
     _protocol:
      Protocol {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        readable: true,
        writable: true,
        _config: [Object],
        _connection: [Circular],
        _callback: null,
        _fatalError: null,
        _quitSequence: null,
        _handshake: true,
        _handshaked: false,
        _ended: false,
        _destroyed: false,
        _queue: [Array],
        _handshakeInitializationPacket: null,
        _parser: [Object] },
     _connectCalled: true,
     state: 'disconnected',
     threadId: null } }
```

Obviously, there's some kind of error, but when I use the try statement, it just skips the catch. What's moore, when I send it to the React app itself, it appears as a **string** of an **empty** flowery brackets! "{}". I have absolutely no idea what's going on. Here is my NodeJS code:-

```
app.get("/retrieve_books", function(req, res) {
  async function getResult(sql) {
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      port: "3306",
      database: "my_books",
      user: "root",
      password: "pokemon2345"
    });
    con.connect();
    try {
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(con.query(sql));
      });
      var answer = await promise;
      console.log("answer");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    con.end();
    return answer;
  }

  var sql = JSON.parse(req.query.msg);
  console.log(sql);
  var answer = getResult(sql);
  console.log(answer);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(answer));
});
```

Here's my React code :-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Form from "./searcherFormDumb";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

function Searcher() {
  const [book, setBook] = useState({
    name: "",
    author: "",
    sno: null,
    series: "",
    type: "",
    genre: "",
    kindleReal: ""
  });
  const defaultState = {
    name: "",
    author: "",
    sno: null,
    series: "",
    type: "",
    genre: "",
    kindleReal: ""
  };

  function handleChange(event) {
    const updatedBook = { ...book, [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
    setBook(updatedBook);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var changed = {};
    function populateChanged(now, old, title, temp) {
      if (now !== old) {
        temp[title] = now;
        return temp;
      } else {
        return temp;
      }
    }
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.name,
      defaultState.name,
      "Book_Name",
      changed
    );
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.author,
      defaultState.author,
      "Author",
      changed
    );
    changed = populateChanged(book.sno, defaultState.sno, "S_no", changed);
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.series,
      defaultState.series,
      "Series_Name",
      changed
    );
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.type,
      defaultState.type,
      "Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel",
      changed
    );
    changed = populateChanged(book.genre, defaultState.genre, "Genre", changed);
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.kindleReal,
      defaultState.kindleReal,
      "Kindle_Real",
      changed
    );
    var temp_string = "";
    var key = "";
    var value = "";
    var temp_string_list = [];
    //debugger;
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(changed).length; i++) {
      //debugger;
      key = Object.keys(changed)[i];
      value = changed[key];
      if (i !== Object.keys(changed).length - 1) {
        temp_string = `${key} = "${value}" AND `;
      } else if (i === Object.keys(changed).length - 1) {
        temp_string = `${key} = "${value}"`;
      }
      temp_string_list.push(temp_string);
      //debugger;
      temp_string = "";
      key = "";
      value = "";
    }

    var sql_t = temp_string_list.join("");
    var sql_tt = "SELECT * FROM books_catalouge WHERE ";
    var sql = sql_tt + sql_t;
    toast.success(sql);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var jsql = JSON.stringify(sql);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      //debugger;
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = this.responseText;
        console.log(typeof response);
      }
    };
    request.open(
      "GET",
      "http://localhost:3001/retrieve_books" + "?msg=" + jsql,
      true
    );
    request.send(jsql);
    console.log("This is the END");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form book={book} onChange={handleChange} onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Searcher;
```

If there is any more detail that is required, please don't hesitate to ask.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if this is the only thing that's incorrect, but look at your SQL statement in the object. If its executing with the double quotes around Alex Scarrow, it'll fail.

Comment: No, I ran the command with the double quotes in my MySQL Workbench. Worked fine.

Comment: Can you send the complete component code where you are calling this?

Comment: Added the entire component code

Comment: There are many connectors to MySQL, you should also specify which library you use (i.e. what is `mysql`).

Comment: I used mysql. 
var mysql = require("mysql");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like several issues with working with async functions in your code.

1. Your handler of `get` request should be also `async` function and use `await` for asynchronous functions.
2. A promise inside `getResult` should be resolved like `con.query(sql, resolve)`

Try this variant.

```
app.get("/retrieve_books", async function(req, res) {
  async function getResult(sql) {
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      port: "3306",
      database: "my_books",
      user: "root",
      password: "pokemon2345"
    });
    con.connect();
    try {
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query(sql, (error, results) => resolve(results));
      });
      var answer = await promise;
      console.log("answer");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    con.end();
    return answer;
  }

  var sql = JSON.parse(req.query.msg);
  console.log(sql);
  var answer = await getResult(sql);
  console.log(answer);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(answer));
});
```

Comment: Returns 'null'.

Comment: I have fixed promise resolving. Please, try again.

Comment: OMG, it works! Thank you so much! This problem had really bugged me. If it's no problem, could you tell me what you changed? Thank you again!

Comment: `resolve(con.query(sql));`  to `con.query(sql, (error, results) => resolve(results));` and `var answer = getResult(sql);` to `var answer = await getResult(sql);`. Plus added `async` function, which handles `get` request

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems. I think they stem from the complexity inherent to this code.

1. `getResult` returns a promise but isn't `await`d or `then`d.

   var answer = getResult(sql);
     console.log(answer);
     res.send(JSON.stringify(answer));

`getResult` returns a promise. you would need to do

```
const answer = await getResult(sql);
```

or

```
getResult(sql)
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(result => res.send(result))
```

2. The promise resolution in `getResult` isn't working as you expect

I would actually simplify this to start and build up from there. Something like this is good

```
app.get("/retrieve_books", function(req, res) {
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "3306",
    database: "my_books",
    user: "root",
    password: "pokemon2345"
  });
  con.connect();
  con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.send(500, 'omgz');
    }
    res.send(result);
    return con.end();
  });
});
```

From here you could sprinkle in promises and async/await.

Comment: Not working. I got the old error again. The one I got before making the query asynchronous.
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: heh, i missed more. There's some issue with the async function `getResult` @kernel72 is on track.